# Topological Property of the Set of Integers

Tags: general-topology

Is the set of integers $ \mathbb{Z}$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual topology?

Comment: It depends. What's the topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @T.Bongers My bad, I should've said that I have the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z} = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n,n+1)$ is a union of open sets and therefore open.  Since the complement of $\mathbb{Z}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is only correct assuming the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @T.Bongers The **usual** topology is what we usually assume we're given!

Comment: I agree with Pedro. If the topology isn't specified, one assumes the usual topology; conversely if the usual topology isn't what is meant, it is the responsibility of the person asking the question to specify the topology.